# REST API- use same URI & same method for different parameter to call different methods

Tags: java, rest, web-services

I have a tricky situation where, I need to use same URI to call POST operation, one with single object & another with array of same type of objects. Issue is I cant change URIs.
e.g.

`POST /my-services/v1/users with single user object as part of request body` &

`POST /my-services/v1/users with array of user objects as part of request body`

I cant change URI for 2nd operation e.g. /my-services/v1/**bulk**-users

So, the question is, how to get such methods added in REST API?

Answer (score 0):

In most JSON mappers (in example `Jackson`) you can set a property `ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY`, Which will basically treat a single object as an array, so you can define your endpoints once (for collections).

Then you implement your endpoint as it always takes a `Collection` as an input, and it will be handled by mapper even if a client will send single JSON object.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>I would say add another param.</strike>

For example,

`POST ... type=single&req=(user object)...` for the first one.

`POST ... type=array&req=[user object]...` for the second one.

The use switch case or if to check the type at the server.

---

Send the data and check the type at the server as Tim says.

Comment: why would you do that if you can just check the object type

Comment: REST returns 404 Not found when request is sent with single object. even when ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY is set. Checking data type is possible when when request is intercepted/ received in implementation method.